# Laravel get error when composer update doctrine/inflector does not exist

Tags: laravel, plugins

I wanna add this plugin to my project
https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

When I updated my comoser.json, app.php, then run composer update.
got this error msg.

```
[RuntimeException]                                                           
  /ProjectPath/vendor/doctrine/inflector does not e  
  xist and could not be created.
```

any idea how to debug this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you've updated both `composer.json` and `app.php` at the same time. What you should do is first add this to `composer.json`:

```
"davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-master"
```

then run this command:

```
composer update
```

and only after that is finished, add these lines to `app/config/app.php`:

```
Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\LaravelPushNotificationServiceProvider
...
'PushNotification' => 'Davibennun\LaravelPushNotification\Facades\PushNotification'
```

Hope this helps.